# React/Javscript how to loop through json file and display

Tags: javascript, html, json, reactjs

I currently have a json file containing data for many people. It is in the following format:

```
    '1': {
        "name": Max
        "age": 8

    },

    '2':
        ....
```

Next, I want to display each of these people as links in my function Foo(). I have written the function below.

```
 import myData from './.../data.json'


 function Foo (){
    return (
        <div>
            <li>

                <Link to={`${url}/1`>{myData[1].name}</Link>}

            </li>
        </div>
    );
}
```

So far, I have done this manually. Now, what I want to do is somehow create a loop and create links for all of the people. I'm thinking of using 'map()' and 'Object.entries()' but I'm unsure of how and where to place them. Should I create a new function for them? I'm not sure....

Comment: Is this json structure something you control? If so you should convert this to an array of objects instead of an object of objects with numbers as keys. You could then just map through the array and display the items.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by calling Object.keys on myData and map the keys to links.

```
import myData from './.../data.json'


function Foo (){
  return (
    <div>
        <li>
          {Object.keys(myData).map(key => <Link to={`${url}/1` key={key}>{myData[key].name}</Link>)}
        </li>
    </div>
);
```

This will loop over all the keys (`"1"`, `"2"`, etc...). You can get the actual item with `myData[key]`. Don't forget to set the `key` property on the `Link`. This will help react to limit the number of needed DOM operations, if you later decide that this data is dynamic.

Comment: Awesome. So that works. How would I add a line break between each name?

Comment: No need for Object keys, just complicates it, instead use  ```Object.values()```
and then ```<Link to={`${url}/1`>{obj.name}</Link>}```

Comment: @EugenSunic beaware that Object.values is not supported in IE11, also don't forget to set the `key` attribute on the `Link` - for this the object-key might be the better fit.

Comment: @DarrelGulseth you might go trough an introduction trough HTML/CSS as is more of a presentation concern. By default a list items render next to each other. You can for example set `display: block` with CSS to the `li` to make it render vertically.